# python queue with multiprocessing, pickling error

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

Why does this code throw me an error:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


def my_process(q):
    print(q.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue(maxsize=4)

    iolock = mp.Lock()
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2, initializer=my_process, initargs=(q))

    for x in range(0,10):
        q.put(x)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'my_process' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

I understand it is something to do with Python pickling of the function that I want to multiprocess but how to fix it?

I have defined the function `my_process` before I defined the pool.

**EDIT:**
python 3.7.3, ipython 7.0.1

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'my_process' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRAMS\Miniconda3_64\envs\py37hdb\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\PROGRAMS\Miniconda3_64\envs\py37hdb\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
```

Comment: I'm guessing could it be because your `initargs` is not a tuple? Try adding a comma after q. `initargs=(q,)`

Comment: Nice try but this is not the case here.

Comment: Hmm, can you provide full stack trace and specific python version? I can run fine with python3.6 after I add in the comma.

Comment: I am using python 3.7.3 with ipython 7.0.1

Comment: Well, I'm also using the exact same version, on linux and I can't reproduce the error, apart from the comma thing.

Comment: Hmm I was running it in ipython and it was failing but it actually runs in terminal.

Comment: Well, runs fine on my ipython 7.5.0. Unreproducible

Comment: I do not want to upgrade ipython version as higher version causes problems with my pycharm version that i can not upgrade. can you downgrade your ipython and see if you experience such problem?

Comment: Nope. Archlinux repo does not contain that specific version. Maybe just maybe you could try upgrading and test? Good luck.

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, what's the name of the module containing your `main`? Are there any modules with similar names inside your ipython? This smells like a "wrong file imported" error. Linux Python uses fork and cannot have this problem, but Windows Python spawns a new python instance, which must recover all the state of the original python, including re-importing files.

Comment: DB_Loader this is the project dir name and main.py is the module file name.